# Multiple linear regression on time series data, is there autocorrelation of residuals?

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, autocorrelation, residuals, diagnostic

I am applying a multiple linear regression model on time series data (independent and all dependent variables are time series). I am wondering if I have concerns of autocorrelation of residuals, by looking at the below plots, in order to evaluate other approaches such as AR. Should I be doing any other checks?

[image: Residuals along time]

[image: ACF]

[image: Fit Values vs Residuals]

Comment: You could also check the partial ACF (PACF, function `pacf` in R) of the residuals.